# If we have $0\leq f'(x)\leq f(x)$, show that $f\equiv0$ if it vanishes at some point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Question:

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable.
>
> Assume that for all $x \in \Bbb R$, $\ 0\le f'(x) \le f(x)$.
>
> Show that $f\equiv 0$, if $f$ vanishes at some point.

I think it is correct graphically.

But I can't solve it formally.

Comment: It is an immediate consequence of Grönwall's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$. Then $g'(x) = -e^{-x} (f(x) - f'(x)) \leq 0$, hence $g$ is non-increasing; also $f$ is non-decreasing from the given conditions.

If $f(x_0) = 0$, then $g(x_0) = 0$, and therefore

- for $x \geq x_0$, $0 \leq e^{-x}f(x) \leq e^{-x_0}f(x_0) = 0$; that forces $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \geq x_0$;
- for $x \leq x_0$, $0 \leq f(x) \leq f(x_0) = 0$; that forces $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Consider the "extreme" cases where $0=f'(x)$ and $f'(x)=f(x)$.

The first case is obvious. Find all the solutions to the each case. Then find how many of those solutions vanish at a point.

Then "squeeze" all other possibilities between these two extreme cases.